# Reading a file containing pathnames to JSON files which are to be loaded

Tags: python, json, scripting, text-files

So, I am trying to read through a textfile with various pathnames of different json files. I want to write a script that then loads each file and print out the json output.

This is what I have written so far:

```
import json

def jsonparse():
    user_path= input("Please enter a path name:")
    with open(user_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            x = f.read()
            jObject = json.loads(x)
            print jObject

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jsonparse()
```

However, this keeps giving me an error. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it. You're using a loop to iterate line by line. You'll want to use the `line` variable itself.

```
for line in f:
    x = line.rstrip()
```

The `.rstrip()` function will remove the inherent trailing newline at the end of your line. Next, you need to use `json.load` to load your JSON data:

```
jObject = json.load(open(x))
```

Putting it all together...

```
def jsonparse():
    user_path = input("Please enter a path name: ")
    with open(user_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            x = line.rstrip()
            jObject = json.load(open(x))
            print jObject
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import json

def jsonparse():
    user_path= input("Please enter a path name:")
    with open(user_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            with open(line) as x:
                jObject = json.loads(x)
                print jObject
```